# issue with sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a

Tags: unity, apt, dpkg

ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` and it gave me the error below. please help

```
 update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general]: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 2: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [gnome_session]: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 7: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general_ubuntu]: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
```

I ran:
    `rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1`

It did not fix my issue, so I ran:
 `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`

It did not fix my issues....

apt-cache policy compiz:

```
Installed: 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150313-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150313-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.9.11.3+14.04.20150313-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:0.9.11+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04

I am also getting this error:

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not sure if they are related

Comment: it my help people figure out your issue to edit your answer with the versions of compiz related packages. Can you post the output of `apt-cache policy compiz` ? What version of Ubuntu are you using? I wonder if you are hitting https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1156294

Comment: updated with the information

Answer (score 0):

So I semi-fixed the issue, I just started over, I backed up all my documentation and reinstalled Ubuntu Desktop. If any one comes up with a better solution let me know.